# Efficient cross-table mySQL queries in Visual Basic

Tags: mysql, database, vb.net

I am currently working on a report-generating application (in Visual Basic) for a pre-existing database (in mySQL), in which I need to submit queries across multiple tables to access all of the information needed; however, my experience with this sort of project is limited.  I am hoping someone can point me toward an efficient method of achieving this.

In the initial report, I need data from 3 tables.

Table 1) 'invoice' - table structure contains a date, an invoice number, and a customer number (and other non-pertinent columns)

Table 2) 'transaction_data' - table structure contains an invoice number, a billing code, and an item description (and other non-pertinent columns).  Each row of the table contains a single line-item from a single invoice (so there can be several rows in this table containing the same invoice number).

Table 3) 'customers' - table structure contains customer number, name, address, phone (and other non-pertinent columns).

I need to be able to search 'invoice' based on dates, to get a list of all invoice numbers within the specified time frame (and their corresponding customer number).  I then need to take that list of invoice numbers, and search 'transaction_data' for each row that contains one of the invoice numbers, and check for a specific billing code.  If the billing code does not exist, I need to use the customer number (obtained during the invoice search) to put together a list of invoice number, customer name, address, phone number.

This can be accomplished fairly easily by populating an array variable utilizing for/while loops, but will require multiple queries across separate tables... of which 'invoice' and 'customers' have 20k+ entries and 'transaction_data' table has over 100k entries.  Surely, this is not the most efficient manner of compiling said data.

Can someone please direct me as to how the query SHOULD be structured efficiently?  Thanks in advance for helping a database noobie!

Answer (score -1):

Look up JOINS in the MySQL manual. You would join the three tables together and with a WHERE clause get the specific rows you need that match the criteria you are searching for. No loops needed.